# getting text from textfield in alerts

Tags: java, webdriver, alert, selenium-webdriver

In our web-aplication we use several alerts like this:

[image]

I need to retrieve link from this alert. 
I did:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String link = alert.getText();
```

But `alert.getText()` returns "Link to copy" not a link in textfield
so how can I get link in this case?

Comment: probably you need to get text box first?
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164894/selenium2-and-webdriver-alert

Comment: I dont know how to get text box from alert.

Comment: Can you try driver.findElement as OP used in the question I have linked?

Comment: I can't use driver.findElement() becouse it is alert, not webelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDriver will be unable to retrieve the link text.
For Windows, you could leverage the Windows Automation API to scrape the text, other operating systems probably have similar APIs that you could utilize - but the short answer is that WebDriver won't be able to do this.