# Can't close a window using driver.close()

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I can't close a window using driver.close() method. When it gets executed, an alert appears.

[image: The alert that comes after driver.close() is executed]

I tried

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

String script = "window.onbeforeunload = null;";

js.executeScript(script);

driver.close();
```

I can't even accept the alert. `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()` is not executed.

I also tried

```
driver.close();

System.out.println("After closing the window");//This line is not executed.
```

Control just stops at `driver.close()` and no exception is thrown and the following lines are not executed.

Comment: the alert is due to browser behaviour which I guess you cannot control

Comment: @AurA I need to close the window. If I can't then I can't execute the next testcases.

Comment: A previous post does handle this alert issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164894/selenium2-and-webdriver-alert

Comment: @AurA The code following the `driver.close()` is not executed. Please find the edited question.

Comment: hope you are initializing the WebDriver properly for the browser you use ... a cross platform solution is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823150/how-to-initialize-multiple-browsers-in-webdriver-using-java  but if that is not the case then you must refer to another previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839075/selenium-webdriver-driver-close. You must also tell us about the stacktrace if you are getting an exception at driver.close()

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic Go to Internet Settings / Security and try lowering the security level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the following method did the job.

```
public void closeWindowByJS(WebDriver driver) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String script = "window.onbeforeunload = null;" + "window.close();";
    js.executeScript(script);
}
```